# Magento List all out of stock items

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to make a cms page which lists all out of stock items.

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
   {

        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
         ->addStoreFilter()
         ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'desc') //<b>THIS WILL SHOW THE LATEST PRODUCTS FIRST</b>
         ->addAttributeToFilter('stock_status', 0)


         ->setPageSize($this->get_prod_count())
         ->setCurPage($this->get_cur_page());
        $this->setProductCollection($collection);
        return $collection;
   }
```

But it is not working. It lists all items. What is the method to list all items which are qty =0 or is_in_stock =0?

Answer (score 7):

Here is the function that I have been using

```
function getOutOfStockProducts()
{
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->joinField(
                        'is_in_stock',
                        'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                        'is_in_stock',
                        'product_id=entity_id',
                        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                        'left'
                )
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', array('eq' => 0));

        return $products;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

you should use different collection for that

```
$outOfStockItems = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_in_stock', 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I ended up using. Gives a list of all the items out of stock on the backend

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
   {


         $stockCollection = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->getCollection()

        /*->addFieldToFilter('is_in_stock', 0);*/ //this can also be used to filter
        ->addFieldToFilter('qty', 0);


$productIds = array();

    foreach ($stockCollection as $item) {
        $productIds[] = $item->getOrigData('product_id');
    }

    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $productCollection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($productCollection)
        ->addIdFilter($productIds)
         ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'desc') //THIS WILL SHOW THE LATEST PRODUCTS FIRST
         ->setPageSize($this->get_prod_count())
         ->setCurPage($this->get_cur_page());
        $this->setProductCollection($productCollection);
        return $productCollection;
   }// _getProductCollection
}// Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Outofstock
```